# Bind object property to combobox

Tags: vb.net, class, oop, combobox, binding

I am trying to add a binding for a `Combobox` with a `class property`. The property is a enumeration. I managed to load the items from the `enum` to the `Combobox` maybe a little unorthodox but it works. (improvement suggestions are also welcome) Then when the form loads the `Combobox` shows the active gender and all the options are in the dropdown menu.

But when I change focus of the `Combobox` to the `button` to test the result it reverts back to male ( in my test I want to change the gender to female ).

How can I make sure the new gender value is passed to my object?

This is my code sample

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Personobject As Person

    Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Personobject = New Person
        Personobject.Gender = GenderEnum.Male

        Dim enumType As Type = GetType(GenderEnum)
        Dim names() As String = [Enum].GetNames(enumType)

        For Each s As String In names
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(s)
        Next

        ComboBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", Personobject, "Gender")
    End Sub

    Private Enum GenderEnum
        Male
        Female
    End Enum

    Private Class Person
        Public Property Gender As GenderEnum
    End Class

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Debug.Print(Personobject.Gender.ToString)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using databinding, then use `ComboBox.DataSource` for binding collection of items for selection and `ComboBox.SelectedValue` as selected value

```
Public Class Form1

    Private _Person As Person

    Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

        ' Bound list of enums to the combobox

        Dim genderList As List(Of GenderEnum) = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(GenderEnum))
                                                  .OfType(Of GenderEnum)
                                                  .ToList()
        ComboBox1.DataSource = genderList

        _Person = New Person With { .Gender = GenderEnum.Male }

        // Bound Person.Gender to the ComboBox.SelectedValue
        ComboBox1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", _Person, NameOf(_Person.Gender), True)

    End Sub

    Private Enum GenderEnum
        Male
        Female
    End Enum

    Private Class Person
        Public Property Gender As GenderEnum
    End Class

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Debug.Print(Personobject.Gender.ToString)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Notice that if you want combobox selected value changed when you update `_person.Gender` somewhere else, than `Person` class need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of `Gender` property.

Comment: I get a error on this line `Dim genderList As New List(Of Gender)([Enum].GetValues(GetType(Gender)))` it won't accept the gender and the potential fixes are not available. Do I need to import something?

Comment: Fixed in the answer. You need convert it to array of `Gender` so it will be `[Enum].GetValues(GetType(Gender)).OfType(Of Gender)`

Comment: Type 'Gender' is not defined. Still the error persist.

Comment: Do not use copy paste :) it is GenderEnum in your code

Comment: Hmmm okay, thought it had to do something with the property. Thank for the information.

Comment: Hi, I the solution given is the answer to my question but. What do I do when the base gender is female? How does the selected item change to female?

Comment: `SelectedValue` will be automatically assigned to the value of `Person.Gender` when binding to it. If you want that updates of `Person.Gender` will reflect to ComboBox then as I mentioned Person class need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. If you have some specific problem fill free to ask another question.